# Android spammy ad highjacking

Tags: gmail, skype

This past day my Android tablet has been showing me invasive fullscreen ads (for Candy Crush, as it turns out, which I've never downloaded) while I've been using skype and gmail app. About one impression every five minutes or so. I'm familiar with mobile ad highjacking on webpages, but this is new, since I don't have a browser "open" and I would have thought that the gmail app sanitized the html that it displays.

So, how exactly are those scummy spammers doing it, and how do I kill it?

Answer (score 0):

gmail runs in the background could try a stop and clear (from your Google Dashboard) which should trap or kill off any cookies